# Google Authentication do I have to verify backend service?

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication

I had configure a Google Authentication and It work fine, but when I wanna change it from test to production, I have to cover some requirements such as the Authorized Domains needs to be verify.

My backend service is stored in azure like for example mysite.azurewebsites.net

I have my homepage store at facebook and my privacy policy store at blogger, so far i was able to verify my privacy policy with blogger, but for the facebook case I had no idea how to achieve that, and for my backend service, what should I do??

its store at azure and the DNS verification gives me a txt to store somewhere.

Is it really necessary to do this in order to have a professional On Screen Auth??

[image]

I just dont know where to put the TXT in my Azure App service, all I know is that if I create a Custom Domain in Azure it gives me CNAME and TXT, but according to Google Search Verification Instrucction Im suppose to set the provided TXT into my Domain provider.

So Both gives me TXT for verification!!!

I only have a mobile app service an all i want from google is to authenticate my users.

I didnt know that in order to have a production OnScreen Auth needed verification so badly!!!

Comment: Your question is not clear on what services you are using, what you have configured and what your problem is. If your backend is on Azure App Service, create a custom DNS name: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain . Once you have DNS for your domain setup correctly, then you can create the URLs and verification records that Google requires.

Comment: I just updated the record, but I need to put that TXT value into my Domain Provider!!!
but azure doesnt let me set that TXT provided by Google, so how do I fix that?

Comment: You need to own your own domain and control of the DNS server. Once you have that completed,  follow the link I provided in my last comment to set up a custom DNS name.

Comment: I have not tried the `URL prefix property" in the message. That might be a workaround. However, in general, Google requires you to own/control your own domain name.

Comment: This link might provide an alternative method: HTML file upload or HTML tag: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9008080

Comment: It isnt a choice for me, all i have is an app service,  that option is for URL and my service address isnt accepted unless its the domain choice.

Comment: I might get back to facebook authentication.